# adding user from sub domain to parent domain via command line

Tags: windows, active-directory

I have domain admin account of root domain(**prime.server.local.net**), i want to add a new user remotely using cmd.exe or powershell.exe to main domain (**prime.server.local.net**) from a windows machine which is joined as a client in child domain (**server.local.net**) . I tried with net user command with /domain parameter but it adds user in sub domain (server.local.net) not in root domain.

Answer (score 0):

Use `New-ADUser` in powershell using the `-server` parameter.

Quoting the [New-ADUser reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-aduser?view=win10-ps):

> -Server
>
> Specifies the AD DS instance to connect to, by providing one of the following values for a corresponding domain name or directory server. The service may be any of the following: AD LDS, AD DS, or Active Directory snapshot instance.